# POST-GET session variable (javascript-php) -javascript takes the previous variable but not last created

Tags: javascript, php, session

From the selected value (from the form) I create a variable (`var parcela`).

```
var parcela;
$(document).ready(function(){
    parcela = localStorage.getItem("parcela");
    if (parcela !== '') {
        $('#parcela').val(parcela);
    }

    $("#parcela").on('change',function() {
        selectBoxVal_1 = $('#parcela').val();
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            localStorage.setItem("parcela", selectBoxVal_1);
        } else {
            alert('Sorry! No Web Storage support..');
        }
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

From the created variable (`parcela`), I create a session variable in PHP.

```
$.post("phpscripts/session.php", {"parc_id": parcela});
```

PHP (session.php)

```
<?php
session_start();

$parcela = $_POST["parc_id"]; 
$parcela_int = (int)$parcela;

if($_POST){
    $_SESSION['parcela_id'] = $parcela_int;
}
?>
```

After that, the created session variable urge to another php script

query.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require("common.php");
$user_id = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id_korisnika']);

$parc = $_SESSION['parcela_id'];

try
{  
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT y_cent, x_cent FROM parcele WHERE id_korisnika='$user_id' AND id_parcele='$parc' ");
$stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
....
```

This all works perfectly!

However, when I call a php script with query (query.php) in javascript, there is a problem. JS takes the previous session variable instead of the last selected.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'phpscripts/query.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success : function(data) {
      chartData = data;
          //console.log(chartData);
...
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? I'm trying for two days to solve this ...

Note: The javascript code is contained in a single script.

Comment: You are missing the beauty and purpose of prepared statements by directly embedding variables within the sql - thus opening the door to potential attackers

Comment: @RamRaider, OK. I agree. Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: So you run the phpscripts/query.php parallel with the phpscripts/session.php script? (based on your note that the javascript is contained in a single script)

Comment: Yes, but query.php works correctly. Generates a query in the last selected variables. When i start php script separately. But when query.php invokes javascript (back) it comes up with the described problem.

Comment: Can you try calling the phpscripts/query.php after the success of the phpscripts/session.php to see if the issue is caused because the two scripts run simultaneously. The session data are stored after the script is terminated or if you call `session_write_close()`

Comment: No, that's not a problem. I tried.  query.php works correctly. Generates a query in the last selected variables. When i start php script separately. But when query.php invokes javascript (back) it comes up with the described problem.

Comment: I am not arguing that the query.php is not working, I think the problem is that you run the session.php and query.php at the same time. You can read some info here http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php **...but as session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161866/discussion-between-knets-and-kamfulebu).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I had to extract part of javascript code that calls the php script into a separate script. I called the new JS script with jQuery `getScript()` Method.

Thank you @knets.